# Asynchronous Not working on my page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using razor engine to build my pages. I want to select Items from my database and get it display Asynchronously. Each time I click on the link, It displays the Correct result from the database BUT loads the partial view into another page instead of the same page. The LoadingElementId="progress" does not display either

Relevant code from my index page

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click to view product List","Reviewed", new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "_LatestReview",                   
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod="GET",
            LoadingElementId="progress"
        })

<div id="_LatestReview">

</div>
```

Partial View of Home controller

```
public PartialViewResult Reviewed()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            var reviewed = ctx.Items.ToList();
            return PartialView("_LatestReview",reviewed);
        }
```

Partial View of View

```
@model IEnumerable<BigDream.Item>

<div >
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Item_ID
    </th>
    <th>
        Item_name
    </th>
    <th>
        Item_Value
    </th>
    <th>
        image_url
    </th>

    <th>
        Item_Description
    </th>
    <th>
        Category_ID
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item_ID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item_name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item_Value)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.image_url)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item_Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category_ID)
    </td>

</tr>
```

}

I feel the problem has to do with the page life cycle to I dont know how to go about it. Can someone help me with this issue

Comment: Have you loaded the unobtrusive Ajax scripts into your page?  https://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive